# chrome api: delete omnibox history

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just write my first chrome extension and I try to delete the omnibox history, but it doesn't work.

I use "chrome.history.deleteAll(function(){})" to delete the whole browser history, but there are still old search queries in the omnibox. Is there any other function I have to call?

Regards,
  Simon.

Edit: So, I disabled the browser synchronization and used the "browsingData" module, but I still have the same problem. I can't delete all queries and URLs in the omnibox. If I use Ctrl+Shift+Del everything works. Why I don't have the same possibilities with this chrome api?...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done with a Chrome Extension.

Comment: Well, I have done it with an "old" and popular extension that erased all history.  Now I have to migrate to manifest version 2 (yes, I know, I should have done this ages ago), but I am getting the same odd behavior with chrome.history.deleteAll